# How to get back to the app after In App Browser view

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, inappbrowser

I have implemented In App Browser-native feature on my app.That feature is working fine.Now I have an issue.When a user clicks the back button of the device after go the web page then It doesn't show any dynamic data on the app.I have implemented data fetching part inside the `constructor()`.Can you tell me how to solve this issue? The app is working fine on other use cases.This only happens when I go to the browser.

This is the [**Video about the issue**](https://youtu.be/B2s0tnNRWuU).

```
constructor(public storage: Storage) {
    super(storage);

    super.getToken().then((val) => {//get token
      this.token = val;
      this.getEventList(this.token);
    });
  }

  //get event list
  getEventList(data): any {

    this.eventData.getEventList(data).subscribe(
      result => {
       this.eventList = this.getManagedEventList(result.eventinfo);
      },
      err => { loading.dismiss(); },
      () => { loading.dismiss(); }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP's feedback:**

This is actually not an issue of the code.This is an issue of the "Ionic View" app.I have installed `.apk` on my android device and no issues.It's working fine.I think there is a huge difference between the simulated environment and the actual device.

**Original Answer:**

Try using a page lifecycle or the platform resume for this (or both)

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public storage: Storage, public plat: Platform) {
  super(storage);

  super.getToken().then((val) => {//get token
    this.token = val;
    this.getEventList(this.token);
  });

  //WHEN YOU USE INAPPBROWSER THE APP IS PAUSED, SO WHEN YOU GO BACK TO IT, IT FIRES A RESUME EVENT
  plat.resume.subscribe(() => {
    //CODE TO GET YOUR LIST
  })
}

// WITH THIS LIFECYCLE EVENT EVERY TIME THE PAGE IS ENTERED (GOING BACK OR FORTH) THE FUNCTION IS FIRED
ionViewWillEnter(){
  //GET THE EVENT LIST
}

//get event list
getEventList(data): any {

  this.eventData.getEventList(data).subscribe(
    result => {
     this.eventList = this.getManagedEventList(result.eventinfo);
    },
    err => { loading.dismiss(); },
    () => { loading.dismiss(); }
  );
}
```

By default you can use the page lifecycle events without any problems, but it throws any error you can try importing `NavController` and use from it.

Hope it helps :)